# Is it possible that the same full JID joins a XMPP MUC multiple times with different user names?

Tags: xmpp

I have a use case where the same **full JID** needs to join the same MUC with different user names.

Is this supported by XMPP and [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible using the standard protocol in [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html). The MUC room uses the full JID to identify the sender for incoming stanzas.

If I were to customize a server to allow this behaviour I would probably look at using [XEP-0172: User Nickname](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html) to signal which nickname a given stanza is supposed to be from.